# Braintree Integration With Parse

Tags: parse-platform, braintree, parse-cloud-code

I am currently trying to integrate Braintree in my cloud code because I would need Marketplaces payment functionalities in my IOS app.

I have been trying to use Braintree Node library by changing the require() paths, but there seems to be Node Modules (called with require(https) for instance) that cause problems.

Can these Node modules be integrated in Cloud Code?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions about our client libraries, you can always [talk to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

[This answer on parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/unable-to-use-node-https-module-in-cloud-code) suggests you copy `http.js` from your node installation into your `cloud/` directory.

That said, I don't believe you'll be able to get the braintree-node client library working on Parse; it relies too much on the Node framework. Please let me know if you do get it working.

Comment: any chance to have braintree take a look and get it to work with parse.com ? I'd really really be interested to do that !

Comment: This is very unfortunate that Parse doesn't have a cloud module for Braintree!